# Magento 2 call admin controller using ajax

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3

I'm trying to call a controller located in `Vendor/Module/Controller/Admin/CustomController/TestAction` but I'm getting an unauthorized error. Below is my code

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'mage/translate',
    ],
    function ($) {
      $("#generate_menu").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : '/admin/vendor_module/CustomController/TestAction',
            type : 'GET',
            data: {
                format: 'json'
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(data) {              
                alert('Data: '+data);
            },
            error : function(request,error)
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
      })
    }
);
```

Note: I don't have any .phtml defined because I'm calling this ajax from a js file and I just added a custom button in the catalog/category in the admin. I know my controller is working it's just that I'm getting an unauthorized access error.

Update:
The JS file calling the Controller is in `/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/mycustom.js`. I have created a custom button that is located in the catalog->category just beside the save button. When I click this the expected behavior is it will trigger the ajax and the ajax will access the controller. But I get the unauthorized problem

Comment: I doubt that your controller works. the namespace is wrong. Vendor/Module/Controllers should be without the s at the end

Comment: Sorry just a typo it's without an S

Comment: You should use getUrl() instead of hard code url

Comment: from where exactly are you trying to call this javascript? you need to be authenticated as an admin!

Comment: within the admin controller. I'll update my question @PhilippSander